# How to pass data from a stateful widget to a stateless in flutter?

Tags: flutter

###### I have a login screen which is stateless and it contains a custom widget which is PhoneFormField as following:

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Form(
        key: _phoneFormKey,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: width * 0.08, right: width * 0.08, top: height * 0.1),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              _buildIntroTexts(context),
              SizedBox(height: height * 0.125),
              ##PhoneFormField(),
              SizedBox(height: height * 0.07),
              _buildnextButton(context),
              //_buildPhoneNumberSubmittedBloc(phoneNumber!),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

###### As you can see the function _buildPhoneNumberSubmittedBloc takes phoneNumber as a parameter which is found inside the PhoneFormField() Widget not inside the LoginScreen

and this is the PhoneFormField:

```
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: height * 0.015),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
              border: Border.all(color: MyColors.lightGrey),
            ),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                final code = await countryPicker.showPicker(context: context);
                setState(() {
                  countryCode = code;
                });
              },
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: countryCode != null
                        ? Text(
                            generateCountryFlag(countryCode!.code),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.sp),
                          )
                        : Text(
                            generateCountryFlag('eg'),
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.sp),
                          ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))),
                    child: countryCode != null
                        ? Text(countryCode!.dialCode,
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.sp))
                        : Text('+20',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.sp)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 16,
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.05),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                border: Border.all(color: MyColors.blue),
              ),
              child: TextFormField(
                autofocus: true,
                //focusNode: FocusNode(),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.sp,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  letterSpacing: 1.5,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Phone Number',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 16.sp,
                    letterSpacing: 1,
                  ),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
                cursorColor: Colors.black,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter your phone number';
                  } else if (value.length < 11) {
                    return 'Please enter a valid phone number';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (newValue) {
                  phoneNumber = newValue;
                },
                onChanged: (value) {
                  phoneNumber = value;
                },
              )),
        )
      ],
    );
```

So how can I make the loginScreen get the value of the String PhoneNumber to pass it to the other functions

Comment: Maybe I read too fast, but do you have a TextEditingController in the State of your loginScreen, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Custom widget class stateless with Constructor taking named parameters used in your widget:

```
class PhoneFormField extends StatelessWidget {

  final String? countryCode;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  const PhoneFormField({Key? key,required this.countryCode,required this.controller, required this.onTap,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        //country picker
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: onTap,
          child: Container(
            child: countryCode != null ? Text("Country Flag") : Text("EG"),
          )
        ),
        ....
        TextField(controller: controller),
        ....
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Now, create stateful login page with required variables that need to be passed to custom widget:

```
class LogInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LogInPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LogInPage> createState() => _LogInPageState();
}

class _LogInPageState extends State<LogInPage> {

  String? countryCode;
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  //make sure to dispose controller

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ....
          PhoneFormField(countryCode: countryCode, controller: controller, onTap: ()async{
            final code = await countryPicker.showPicker(context: context);
            setState(() {
              countryCode = code;
            });
          }),
          ....
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To check the TextField's value use `controller.text`:

```
void phoneText(){
  debugPrint("${controller.text}");
}
```